# Laravel 4 Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: email, laravel-4, swiftmailer

When I send mail I see this message

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "" using 3 possible authenticators
```

My config mail.php

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => '******', // here addres host
'port' => 465,
'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => '******', //name user email
'password' => '******',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false
```

Log

```
[2015-11-08 23:10:53] NULL.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "office@***.com" using 3 possible authenticators' in C:\git\project-www\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\Esmtp\AuthHandler.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 C:\git\project-www\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(307): Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport))
#1 C:\git\project-www\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(118): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand()
#2 C:\git\project-www\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#3 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(307): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#4 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(134): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#5 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(214): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('emails.clientas...', Array, Object(Closure))
#6 C:\git\project-www\app\models\core\Contact.php(101): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#7 C:\git\project-www\app\models\core\Contact.php(101): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('emails.clientas...', Array, Object(Closure))
#8 C:\git\project-www\app\controllers\core\HomeController.php(159): Project\Models\core\Contact::sendMailFromClient()
#9 [internal function]: HomeController->postSendEmailFromClient()
#10 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postSendEmailFr...', Array)
#12 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(HomeController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'postSendEmailFr...')
#13 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(934): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'HomeController', 'postSendEmailFr...')
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#15 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(104): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#16 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1000): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(968): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(738): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(708): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#21 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#22 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#23 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#24 C:\git\project-www\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#25 C:\git\project-www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(606): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 C:\git\project-www\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#27 {main} [] []
```

How can I resolve problem? Who now?

**UPDATE**
I fixed this problem. Client have wrong certifcate on domain and wrong password.

Comment: Is Gmail the host? Please, post exception too.

Comment: No, it diffrent service where my client have hosting

Comment: Post exception or stacktrace from log.

Comment: it fills like your host ip is block or on spam list of google system. solution using free stmp service is bad idea, I suggesting using api like mandrill or mailgun

Comment: I added the log in question. The project I'm currently running in XAMPP. The same problem arises how to run the project in a virtual server, but under a different domain than I configure e-mail.
Now, I think that this could be a problem. I check tomorrow as I move the service to produce or begins to work sending mail. Because it can issue the certificate.

Comment: I fixed this problem. Client have wrong certifcate on domain and wrong password.